# what is cairo required by GTK 2.9 to compile (on Lucid Lynx)?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gtk, cairo, ubuntu-10.04

I have been trying to run configure to prepare the make file for GTK 2,9 on a fresh Linux box (running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx).

it complained about some dependencies, including:

- glib-2.0
- atk (1.29.2)
- pango (1.20)
- cairo (1.6)

I managed to find the glib 2.22.0, downloaded the atk but did not compile yet, did not start the pango yet, but when tried to get the cairo package I didn't know where to get it from!

nothing on GNU site, not on GTK site!

anyone knows where to get it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [cairographics.org](http://cairographics.org/), it's Cairo's official home. Latest available source archive in the [releases file list](http://cairographics.org/releases/) seems to be [1.8.10](http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.8.10.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks, I will use in this case `sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev`